# Typescript 0.8.2 project compile error

Tags: typescript

I installed Typescript 0.8.2 plugin for visual studio 2012.

I recreated my project from scratch but am now getting this compile error.

"tsc  --comments --sourcemap --target ES3"  exited with code 1

Answer (score 1):

In your project file, the full path to `tsc` is normally specified. The path is probably incorrect.

You can check it using these steps.

1. Right-click on the project and select "Unload"
2. Right-click on the unloaded project and select "Edit"
3. Look for the following code (might be slightly different to this):

Project File:

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(PROGRAMFILES)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.2.0\tsc&quot; --comments --sourcemap --target ES3 @(TypeScriptCompile ->'&quot;%(fullpath)&quot;', ' ')" IgnoreExitCode="true" />
  </Target>
```

Previously the `tsc` path was:

```
$(PROGRAMFILES)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\?.?.?.?\tsc
```

But I noticed in the latest version it is:

```
$(PROGRAMFILES)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\tsc
```

i.e. no version number.

It is probably worth noting that `ES3` is the default, so you don't need to pass it - but there is no harm in passing it.

Comment: I haven't tried. I've actually gone back to using 0.8.0.0. I will try it out later.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a daft question, but have you got any Typescript (.ts) files in the project?
I got this error when I created a new project, deleted app.ts and tried to compile.

Looks like it fails to build the project if there are no .ts files passed to the compiler. Issue is still present today...

Adding a new .ts file into the project fixed it...